# UX/UI design for saving an edited picture automatically without overwriting previous one

Tags: c#, c++, c

I am trying to save a picture/images after making changes on it, but it is overwriting the old one. Is there a way i can design my UI so the edited picture can be saved separately.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What GUI toolkit, what OS? Please show some code.

Comment: Also explain why this has somthing to do with UX/UI. While when you save the edited Picture and overwriting the old one It sounds more like just a coding Problem. Do you also want to show the 2 pictures after them being edited or what is the wanted end result?

Comment: Can you change the filename that the file writes to by default? eg: `my_picture.png` is the original, and once you have edited it you save it to `my_picture_1.png`